# Search a substring with Strings.InStr or IndexOf produces no result

Tags: string, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a string defined like:

```
 Dim str As String = "A.090173.R-G1 00 NR 1,00 5 BAR (desc) * SEE NOTE : Mat. 17K Dim. xx*yy mm"
```

I need to discover if there is this substring present".090173.R-G"
I have tried this code:

```
Dim ssf As String = ".090173.R-G"
Dim Test1 As Integer = InStr(str, ssf)
Dim Test2 As Integer = str.IndexOf(ssf)
Dim Test3 As Boolean = str.Contains(ssf )
```

But in all cases I have no valid result.
Test1 returns 0
Test2 returns -1
Test3 False
What's wrong?

Comment: Put quotes around your string literal.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in the copy code here.

Comment: Copied your code and I get results. I get "2", "1" and "True" respectively. I wonder if the hyphen is a special character on your side.

Comment: It can be. I use Itext7 for reading the str string value from a PDF file. Then I use the compare metodes for find the substring. If I copy from the dubugger the values and I paste here, then I open a new VisualStudo solution, you are in right, it works.

Comment: Solved with Regex.Replace(str , "[^\w\@-]", "").Contains(ssf )